# copying one element of a char array to another using for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I'm trying to write a simple program which takes an array of chars, and spits it out backwards. I know there are plenty of other ways to shorten this using a library header function, but I wanted to do it using for loops just to get used to them.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

char string1[10];
int count = 0;
char stringy[10];

void enterString()
{
    cout << "please enter a string: " << endl;
    cin >> string1;
}

void stringCounter(const char stringLength[])
{
    //initiate for loop i = 0
    //if stringLength[i] does not does not equal 'i' then carry on
    //increment i
    for (int i = 0; stringLength[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {   
        count++;
    }   
    cout << "size of string is: " << count << endl;
}

void reverseString(int arraySize, char string2[])
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = arraySize; i >= 0; string2[i--])
    {   
        stringy[counter] = string2[i];
        counter++;
    }   
    stringy[count] = '\0';
    cout << stringy << endl;
}

int main()
{
enterString();
stringCounter(string1);
reverseString(count, string1);
return 0;
}
```

This is the whole program. The program is failing in function `reverseString`. I can't work out how to successfully read the last index of the `char array string2[]` and copy it into the first index of `char array stringy`.

Comment: why the `string2[i--]` instead of just `i--` in the for loop?

Comment: @KarstenKoop I actually have no clue... you're totally correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One, If the user enters a string more than 10 characters long then your `enterString()` function will access the array out of its bound, at `cin>>string1`. So better to use [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) to make sure you don't read more than what your array can hold.

Two, with your current implementation the `reverseString()` function will write to the first element of the array with the null terminator character,if the `arraySize<=10`, and trying to display that string will not show you anything.

This:

```
 cin >> string1;//will try to access the array out of its bound if user give more than it can hold,i.e 10 characters

 ...

 for (int i = arraySize; i >= 0; string2[i--])
 {   
    stringy[counter] = string2[i];//the first iteration will put the '\0' character as the first elements of stringy
     counter++;
 }
```

Should be changed to:

```
cin.getline(string1,10);//make sure to get not more than 10 characters,including the null terminator

 .....

for (int i = arraySize-1; i >= 0; i--)
{   
    stringy[counter] = string2[i];
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Great, that explains it! Thanks

Comment: Hi @bkVnet, can you explain how I would implement getline to make sure I don't read in more chars than my array can hold?

Comment: @nrs90 The first argument of `getline` is the destination where the string that is read will be put, the second argument is the number of characters to read. So,for example, if you have an array named `destination` which can hold `n` number of elements then you say `cin.getline(destination,n)` to read a maximum of `n` character from the stream which is the maximum your array can hold.

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes in your program. If this is the exact code you are compiling then it should throw many errors.
Following might help.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void reverseString(int , char *);
int stringCounter(const char );

int stringCounter(const char stringLength[])
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; stringLength[i] != '\0'; i++)
        count++;
    cout << "size of string is: " << count << endl;
    return count;
}
void reverseString(int arraySize, char string2[])
{
    int counter = 0;
    char stringy[100];
    for (int i = arraySize - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        stringy[counter] = string2[i];
        counter++;
    }
    stringy[counter] = '\0';
    cout << stringy << endl;
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "string";
    reverseString(stringCounter(str),str);

    return 0;
}
```